# Bring Live Wallpaper to Front

Tags: java, android, live-wallpaper

I had originally asked another question, but I think I found a work-around, which presents a new question hah!

I think my question is fairly basic, and I have searched for anything relevant.

When you are setting a live wallpaper in android, before you set the wallpaper, you have a chance to view the wallpaper without being in the background with all of your icons above it.  A sort of "preview" of the wallpaper.

Is there a simple java code to force this activity, on a double tap for instance?  I want the user to be able to bring the wallpaper to the front on demand basically.

Maybe this isn't possible, but I assume it is as you can do it before you actually set the wallpaper.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Jack

Edit-

I should note I think I found a similar question but the English is so bad I can't tell:

[How to make directly show live wallpaper in main activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23620675/how-to-make-directly-show-live-wallpaper-in-main-activity)

```
    public void StartActivity() {

    WallpaperInfo localWallpaperInfo = ((WallpaperManager) getSystemService("wallpaper")).getWallpaperInfo();
    if (localWallpaperInfo != null) {
        String str1 = localWallpaperInfo.getSettingsActivity();

        if (str1 != null) {
            String str2 = localWallpaperInfo.getPackageName();
            Intent localIntent1 = new Intent();
            ComponentName localComponentName = new ComponentName(str2, str1);
            localIntent1.setComponent(localComponentName);
            localIntent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(localIntent1);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
`wallpaper.bringToFront();` With a double tap listener.

Or you can use the answer on the question you have in your edit.

Comment: Ah ok, I honestly couldn't understand the question at all from the other link I had, so I wasn't sure if the response was correct or not haha.

Comment: Well, I got it to bring the settings to front, but I want it to bring the live wallpaper service itself to the front.  Any ideas?  I have added my code to the OP.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't sure with your question. Try this tutorial by Vogella, they make great tutorials! http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidLiveWallpaper/article.html

Comment: Yea the tutorial is good, but still doesn't answer my original question.  I could just be reading it wrong.  I already have my live wallpaper app done, it works great.  But now I just want the ability to bring it to the front, so the user can interact with it without the distraction of the app icons, widgets, etc.